# API Request $_POST returning empty array

Tags: php, json, api, rest, post

I'm using Zurmo and trying to create a new account using REST API. I followed this documentation precisely: http://zurmo.org/wiki/rest-api-specification-accounts to pass the required parameters as json array.

This is my php code:

public function actionCreateOrUpdate()
        {

```
     $params=$_POST;
    $modelClassName=$this->getModelName();

    foreach ($params as $param)

    {
        if (!isset($param))
        {
            $message = Zurmo::t('ZurmoModule', 'Please provide data.');
            throw new ApiException($message);
        }

            $r=$this->GetParam($param);

            $res= array('status' => 'SUCCESS',  'data' => array($r));


            print_r(json_encode($res,true));

     }

    }     

 function GetParam ($param){
        $modelClassName=$this->getModelName();



        if (isset($param['mobile_id'] ) && !$param['mobile_id']=='' &&!$param['mobile_id']==null)
        {   $id=$param['mobile_id'];

        $params=array();

            foreach ($param as $k => $v) {

                if(!($k=='mobile_id')) {

                    $params[$k] = $v;}



            }
            if ($params=null){$message = Zurmo::t('ZurmoModule', 'Please provide data.');
            throw new ApiException($message);}

        $tableName = $modelClassName::getTableName();
        $beans = ZurmoRedBean::find($tableName, "mobile_id = '$id'");

        if (count($beans) > 0)
        {
            $result    =  $this->processUpdate($id, $params);
        }else{
            $result    =  $this->processCreate($params,$id);
        }
    }

          return $result;

    }
```

The problem is that the $_POST method is returning an empty array. While debugging I tried to use print_r($_POST) and it also returned an empty array. I also tried to pass parameters as plain text and got the same result. I tried $_GET method and it worked. I think the problem is in the $_POST method, maybe I need to change something in my .php files. Any ideas please?

Comment: Can you show the request? If `$_GET` is working and not `$_POST` you might be missing the request type when you send it.

Comment: the request type is REST. I also tried to use the HTTPRequester but it gave the same result :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first hit the api with static data, to check if it works fine, then try to integrate php within that static data. You will need to read the documentation for which action accepts which format, and which method is supported(`GET OR POST`). Then try `die();` , before sending if the array formed is as per the documentation.

Comment: Actually I tried hitting the api with static data and it worked. And the method I'm implementing supports POST. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue when creating Account using REST API from java client. The problem was I did not send the proper POST request.
Another symptom also was on server side `print_r(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);` php code returned the correct request data.

Specifically the root cause was:

- The Content-Type HTTP header was not "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
- The value field value in POST request was not properly encoded ( I used java.net.URLEncoder.encode method to overcome this)

After fixing these it worked.